# How can I write a function in Golang which takes multiple types as a parameter?

Tags: function, go, interface

I am trying to write a function in Golang which will serialize a map and a slice (convert it to a string). I want it to take one parameter but I am unsure of how to make it accept a map and a slice only. I know I can use something like the following function but beyond this point I am confused. I am still trying to wrap my head around interfaces.

```
func Serialize(data interface{}) string {
    return ""
}
```

It is preferred if I don't need to create my own struct for it. An explanation of how I could allow this Serialize function to accept maps and structs would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I am aiming for something similar to the fmt.Println function how it accepts nearly any built-in type.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the kind of thing you can't do without having multiple functions, an interface, or using reflect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `fmt.Sprintf` for this:

```
type foo struct {
    bar  string
    more int
}

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    fmt.Println(Serialize(s))

    m := map[string]string{"a": "a", "b": "b"}
    fmt.Println(Serialize(m))

    t := foo{"x", 7}    
    fmt.Println(Serialize(t))
}

func Serialize(data interface{}) string {
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%v", data)
    return str
}
```

This will print:

`[a b c]`

`map[b:b a:a]`

`{x 7}`

You can easily trim off the `{}`, `[]` and `map[]` if desired/required with `strings.TrimSuffix` and `strings.TrimPrefix`

Comment: @Acidic, while this answer provides you with a solution, it does not explain how `fmt.Printf()` manages to achieve it. If you're interested in how a Go function might deal with arguments of varying types, you might read up on [type switches](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch) and [reflection](https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+reflection). And the fact you did not know at least about the first one suggests you did not read an introductory book on Go; please do!